# Call ActiveX method from JavaScript in IE9

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-9

I have an activex control on the page. Usually, to call it methods I use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('activexControlID').MethodName(2) = 'value string';
```

I know, that it may looks strange, but it works fine in IE6, IE7, IE8. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE9. It throws the error "Cannot assign to a function result".

I already tried:

```
document.getElementById('activexControlID').MethodName[2] = 'value string';
// and
document.getElementById('activexControlID').MethodName(2, 'value string');
```

but with no luck.

**UPDATE**

The expression `document.getElementById('activexControlID').MethodName(2) = 'value string';` do not suppose to return a value. It acts like a setter. After all, I can get it later with the code `var value = document.getElementById('activexControlID').MethodName(2);` And I can get the value in IE9. But can not set it.

I don't know how it is implemented inside the activex control, but it is similar to array, just uses *()* instead of *[]*. And once again, it works in previous versions of IE.

**UPDATE 2**

Looks like a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/606963/this-error-occurs-when-using-atl-property-script5003-cannot-assign-to-function-result) in IE9. Hope will be fixed.

Comment: What is `.MethodName(2)` supposed to return?

Comment: Don't use activeX controls in IE9. IE9 is cross-browser compatibile enough to use real web applications.

Comment: does the control run in Medium or High Security? Scripting can be disabled then towards ActiveX controls. Check your settings... ;)

Comment: People still use ActiveX? People still use IE?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use an indexer method? What's the control? What is it implemented in? If you use the F12 Developer Tools to put the page in IE8 Mode, does the page work?

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT  Yes, when I put Internet Explorer 9 into IE8-mode it works as expected. The activex control are used to work with files. User can select files and, for example, can set description for that files, using api like control.setFileDescription(index) = 'fiel descrption', where index is the index of selected file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed and the code

```
document.getElementById('activexControlID').MethodName(2) = 'some value';
```

now works in the IE9 RC1.